# Script to import information from csv to auto send email from outlook

Tags: powershell, email

Pretty new to this so bear with me.....

I am attempting to find a way to be able to import a CSV list including name, email, subject and a word (info) to the body of the email , and send it via Outlook and then go to the next line send that out, so on and so forth till all emails have been sent out. So the email may look like:

Email: $email

Subject: $subject

Body:

$name,

Hello! blah blah blah blah blah $info blah blah blah

Thank You,

end

I am looking to send out many from one list it will all be the same generic email but with certain words changed so looking to cut down on hand emailing time.

I have tried and successfully sent out one email with a script but that is it

Here is what I found to attempt to work off of

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0) 
$Mail.To = "todd@emconsultinginc.com" 
$Mail.Subject = "test" 
$Mail.Body ="test"
$Mail.Send()
```

This is where I got to. I was able to get it to pull from a CSV with each line. Now I am wondering if we can pull the content from a word doc, keeping formatting and send it. I tried to pull the Word Doc info but I do not think I am quite there. Any suggestions?

```
$Mail.Send()



$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$csv = Import-Csv C:\code\test.csv 
$wd = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$doc = $wd.Documents.Open("C:\code\test.html")
$doc.Range().text

foreach ($line in $csv){

$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = $line.Email
$Mail.Subject = $line.Subject
$Name = $Line.Name
$body = $doc.Text
$Mail.Body ="Hello $Name, $body





$Mail.Send()
}
```

Comment: Could you post the script that you used?

Comment: Welcome as a new user to [SO]. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. SO isn't a free script writing service nor a forum, but a site for programmers helping colleagues who got stuck with a distinct problem. Own research and ***serious*** coding attempts are expected.